# How to detect a NFC P2P event

Tags: android, nfc, ndef, nfc-p2p, android-beam

Android allows you to prepare NFC push messages using either `NfcAdapter.setPushMessage` or `NfcAdapter.setPushMessageCallback`. My understanding is that after setting the push message or callback, the message will be sent on the next NFC event (such as tapping two phones together).

Is there a way to detect when that event has happened?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, [`NfcAdapter.setOnNdefPushCompleteCallback()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/nfc/NfcAdapter#setOnNdefPushCompleteCallback(android.nfc.NfcAdapter.OnNdefPushCompleteCallback,%20android.app.Activity,%20android.app.Activity...)) allows you to register a callback for exactly that purpose: get a notification when the NDEF message was successfully transfered to the other device.

Btw. the `CreateNdefMessageCallback` (registered by [`NfcAdapter.setNdefPushMessageCallback()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/nfc/NfcAdapter.html#setNdefPushMessageCallback(android.nfc.NfcAdapter.CreateNdefMessageCallback,%20android.app.Activity,%20android.app.Activity...))) is typically called as soon as a device capable of receiving the NDEF message is in range. So you can even approximate the start and the end of the NDEF push (Beam) transaction.